# Vector subtraction python 3 without using the built in functions sum, min, max and zip

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector

I'm fairly new to coding in the python 3 language. I am writing a code that, first, it will check the dimensions of two vectors, then if the dimensions match, it will compute the subtraction of the two vectors. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with my code any help would be great. Thank you in advance.

```
def vecSubtract(vector01,vector02):
    if len(vector01) != len(vector02):
        raise ValueError
    result = []
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(vector01)):
        total += vector01[i] - vector02[i]
        result.append(total)
    return result
vector01 = [2, 3, 4]
vector02 = [4, 2, 1]
print(vecSubtract(vector01,vector02))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sub(vec1, vec2):
       if len(vec1) != len(vec2):
           raise ValueError
       return [a - b for a, b in zip(vec1, vec2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without actually running it, it looks like the line
total += vector01[i] - vector02[i]
is your problem. Just replace the "+=" with "=".
And best not to call the result total as it is just one term in a sequence.

The question is a good one as it requires code that could be understood without learning the idiosyncratic python functions.